# android error: "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})"

Tags: android

trying to create a basic android program:
i have created two buttons and a text view in fragment_main.xml
and when i was writing the basic code i have got some error line(red line) on setOnClickListener method saying 
***"The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})"***

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView display;
    Button add;
    Button sub;
    int counter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
        TextView display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        add.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this :

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

    }
});
```

Also check that you have imported the following

`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: i have already done the same when i inclulded "@override" it is again displaying an error at view. so i have deleted that statement and i have already included import android.veiw.View.OnClickListener;